# Minimum account balance for New Zealand visa

Tags: visas, new-zealand, proof-provenance-of-funds

We are visiting New Zealand for our honeymoon in March-April. As per visa regulations, we must have 1,000 NZD in our account. The minimum visa duration is 3 months. So, should each of us have 1,000 NZD in our account or 3,000 NZD?

Comment: How long are you staying? It doesn't matter that the visa has 3 months validity if you are just staying one month.

Comment: 15 days. So we need to have only 1000 NZD in each account?

Answer (score 3):

According to Immigration NZ, you are **each** expected to have access to **at least** NZ$1000 **per month of your actual stay**, or NZ$400 in the case of prepaid accommodation.

As you are staying for 15 days and this is half of a month, you will each need to have half of this amount.

Remember that this is additional to the funds required for any further travel if you have not yet purchased the exit ticket, and will barely cover the minimum needs of a traveller (i.e. food).

Therefore, you together will need a minimum total of NZ$1000 (or NZ$400 with prepaid accomodation) and should plan to have more where possible, especially if you will spend some of this money on entertainment or for other travel purposes.